# Textpad syntax definition for files without extension

Tags: textpad, document-class

In Textpad, is there a way to assign a syntax definition to files without an extension? The default document class does not appear to allow assignment of a syntax definition file.

I want to assign my PHP definition to files without an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I will avoid asking why you have PHP in files with no extension -- .php is always valid.

Try setting the syntax for the Default document class.